# CodeMirror Line-Break doesn't add line number - Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, codemirror, ngx-codemirror

I'm using code mirror from ngx-codemirror. I want to split the line when it fits to the width of the parent. I have found some solutions to split the like using,

```
lineWrapping: true
```

and in styles

```
.CodeMirror-wrap pre {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

Using this I was able to split the line but I need to show the line number too.
The line number is not shown for the line that was just split.
This is the stackblitz link to my issue : [code-mirror-line-break-issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/code-mirror-line-break-issue)

Screenshot :
[image]

Please help me with this.

Comment: This looks like normal behaviour to me, but you want the same line number displayed twice or more is a line is split?

Comment: I didn't quite get your requirements. Can you please attach some screenshot that reflects your expectations?

Comment: @David Actually I need line number for each line(consecutive) even if the line is split. Can u please check the screenshot updated and also the stackblitz link

Comment: @yurzui I have attached the screenshot. Could you please check that as well as the stackblitz link? Line numbers should be shown consecutively on each line

Comment: OK, I get it now, but this is a bit counter intuitive. Say 2 persons discussing on a phone/web chat about a piece of code/json. They will not see the same thing when one mentions a line number to the other if they have different windows/screen sizes

Comment: Thats right @David. But right now I'm in a particular scenario where this is required

Comment: can you give a bit more of background infos, why this is required? Because maybe your particular problem can be solved in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not feasible using Code Mirror options, as this is something that is a bit counter intuitive that is rarely (ever?) wanted.

Like I said in my comment, say 2 persons discussing on a phone/web chat about a piece of code/json. They will not see the same thing when one mentions a line number to the other if they have different windows/screen sizes

**Solution**

As a hack, you can create your own elements representing line numbers and place them over the default line numbers.

Here is the [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/code-mirror-line-break-issue-31yei1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

**Note**: This a a very basic example. If you change code mirror settings (font size, gutters,...), you might need to tweak the css or do more calculation based on these settings.

**component.html**

```
<div class='codeMirrorContainer'>
  <ngx-codemirror
      #codeMirror
      [options]="codeMirrorOptions"
      [(ngModel)]="codeObj"
    ></ngx-codemirror>

<ul class='lineContainer' [style.top.px]="-topPosition">
  <li [style.width.px]='lineWidth' *ngFor="let line of lines">{{line}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**component.css**

```
li
{
  height: 19px;
  list-style: none;
}

.codeMirrorContainer
{
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lineContainer
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  
}

::ng-deep .CodeMirror-linenumber
{
  visibility: hidden; /* Hides default line numbers */
}
```

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent
{


  @ViewChild('codeMirror') codeMirrorCmpt: CodemirrorComponent;

  private lineHeight: number;
  public lineWidth;

  public topPosition: number;
  public lines = [];

  codeMirrorOptions: any = ....;
  codeObj :any = ...;

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef)
  {
  }



  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    this.codeMirrorCmpt.codeMirror.on('refresh', () => this.refreshLines());
    this.codeMirrorCmpt.codeMirror.on('scroll', () => this.refreshLines());
    setTimeout(() => this.refreshLines(), 500)

  }


  refreshLines()
  {
    let editor = this.codeMirrorCmpt.codeMirror;
    let height = editor.doc.height;
    this.lineHeight = editor.display.cachedTextHeight ? editor.display.cachedTextHeight : this.lineHeight;
    if (!this.lineHeight)
    {
      return;
    }
    let nbLines = Math.round(height / this.lineHeight);
    this.lines = Array(nbLines).fill(0).map((v, idx) => idx + 1);
    this.lineWidth = editor.display.lineNumWidth;
    this.topPosition = document.querySelector('.CodeMirror-scroll').scrollTop;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();

  }


}
```

Comment: It's a bit tricky yet it really helps! Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Welcome. Yes it's tricky, but what you are asking for is not common